# How to assign a class to a XSL element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSL tag:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
              <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="QuickLink" />
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/NewsArticle/artTitle" />
            </xsl:element>
```

How do I assign a class to the link `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is an attribute.  You can add it the same way you added the href attribute.

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="QuickLink" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:value-of select="some-class-name" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/NewsArticle/artTitle" />
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Thank you. Would I be able to add the `title` tag the same way?

Comment: Yes.  It is the structure that is important.  You can add a tag named anything you want.

Comment: So in this case the name would be `title`?

Comment: Correct.  You would do it the exact same way.  Just change the name to title.

Comment: I was trying to add two classes, but it wasn't allowing me to.

Comment: You can't add two attributes with the same name.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, unless you need to compute an element name you don't need `xsl:element`, you can simply write a literal result element:

```
<a href="{QuickLink}" class="some-class-name"><xsl:value-of select="Html/root/NewsArticle/artTitle"/></a>
```